# Completely rearrange Table element with media query

Tags: html, css, html-table, media-queries, smartphone

I'm trying to rearrange a relatively large table (using CSS media query) after the width of a screen reaches a certain point and have it look like this (see image below) when the browser window is squished all the way through:

[image: Desired table format]

I've already succeed at deleting the unwanted rows, and getting the basic layout of it.

**The Problem is:**
the inline block elements below each day of the week need to fit the width of the table, and nothing has worked so far, not flex (maybe I'm not using it correctly) or overflow, or border-box.

**HTML**  (just a table)

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DAY</th>
                <th style="width:300px;">CLASS</th>
                <th>TIME</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td>Endurance biking</td>
                <td>9am-1pm</td>
                <td><a href="#bannerMain">Register</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td>Speed biking</td>
                <td>2pm-4pm</td>
                <td><a href="#bannerMain">Register</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="toBeDeleted">
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td colspan="3" class="noClasses">No classes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thursday</td>
                <td>Speed biking</td>
                <td>3pm-5pm</td>
                <td><a href="#bannerMain">Register</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="toBeDeleted">
                <td>Friday</td>
                <td colspan="3" class="noClasses">No classes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Saturday</td>
                <td>Endurance biking</td>
                <td>9am-1pm</td>
                <td><a href="#bannerMain">Register</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sunday</td>
                <td>Endurance biking</td>
                <td>10am-4pm</td>
                <td><a href="#bannerMain">Register</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**CSS**  (deletes 2 rows and the "thead", colors every first cell of each row and place that cell above the rest of it's respective row)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 530px){
thead, .pasDeClasses{
    display: none;
}
td:first-child{
    background-color: #4080bc;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
}
tr > td{
    border-left: 1px solid  white;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
}
table{
    min-width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Arial;
}    
}    
thead{    
    background-color: #4080bc;
    color: white;
}    

td{
background-color: #d6d6d6;
padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 
30px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try absolute-positioning only the last `tr` elements at the bottom of their parents. notice the `position:relative`, and `display:block` on the parent `tr`

```
tr{
  display:block;position:relative;padding-bottom:20px
}
tr td:last-child{
  position:absolute;bottom:0;
  width:100%;height:20px
}
```

This works using the rule that an absolutely positioned element inside of a relatively positioned element will "dock" to the relatively positioned parent-element, rather than the viewport.

Comment: absolute-positioning just rips those `td` elements right out of the table and sends them flying somewhere else in the page.

Comment: If I could just wrap those 3 `td` elements in the html with something, and then add the necessary properties (display: inline-block) to that wrapper, it would solve everything, but I don't know of any wrapper elements that can be used inside a table in that way, you?

Comment: edited my answer, you'll need display:block on the parent `tr`